How can I provide application access to the sign-in logs of an enterprise application without granting AuditLog.Read.All across the entire directory?
The owners of an enterprise application are able to view the sign-in- and audit logs of the enterprise application in the Azure Portal, being granted only the Directory.Read.All Entra ID role.
I need to process these activity logs in the context of an application, but the only MS Graph endpoint exposing this information, GET /auditLogs/directoryaudits, requires the AuditLog.Read.All and Directory.Read.All, which are directory wide and too privileged.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
Is there any way to grant an application access to only its own sign-in logs or to the activity logs for a set of enterprise applications, not requiring the permission to read activity logs across the entire directory?

No there is no way  to grant an application access to only its own sign-in logs or to the activity logs for a set of enterprise applications

Thank you. How come the user has access to read the sign-in logs for an owned enterprise application?

If the user is signing in to the application and the Token has AuditLog.Read.All and Directory.Read.All scopes then the user will be able to read sign-in logs

But only to owned applications, right? The user doesn't have Directory.Read.All, but Directory.AccessAsUser.All with the Directory Readers Entra role

I guess for all applications as the user has Directory Readers Entra role

No, only owned applications, so it's not all

What do you mean?
